# Putting only selected checkboxes in a PhP variable, then displaying that variable underneath

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to get selected values (of which multiple selections are possible) from my database generated dropdown menu and store those into a PhP variable. I then wish to display the content of that variable into a simple div element below.
This is my code so far which results in nothing inside my simple div:

```
<form id="menu1" method="POST">
        <h2>Area Code</h2>
        <select id="multi-select1" name="multi_select1" multiple="multiple">
            <?php
                //The query asking from our database
                $areaCodeSQL = "SELECT ac.Number AS `AreaCode`, ac.Name AS `AreaName`
                                FROM `AreaCodes` ac";                                                               //SQL query: From the table 'AreaCodes' select 'Number' and put into 'AreaCode', select Name and put into 'AreaName'

                $areaCodeResults = $conn->query($areaCodeSQL);                                                      // put results of SQL query into this variable

                if ($areaCodeResults->num_rows > 0) {                                                               // if num_rows(from $results) is greater than 0, then do this:
                    // output data of each row
                                foreach($areaCodeResults as $areaCodeResult)                                        //for each item in $areCodeResults do this:
                                    {
                                        $areaNameAndCode =  $areaCodeResult['AreaCode'] ." ". $areaCodeResult['AreaName'];  //get AreaCode and AreaName from query result and concat them
                                        $areaName = $areaCodeResult['AreaName'];                                    // get AreaName
                                        $areaCode = $areaCodeResult['AreaCode'];                                    //get AreaCode

                                        ?><option class="menuoption1" name="menuAreaCode" value="<?php echo $areaCode ?>"  ><?php echo $areaNameAndCode; ?></option><?php  //Create this option element populated with query result variables
                                    }
                } 
                $result = $_POST['multi_select1'];                   
            ?>
        </select>   
    </form>

 <div id="showResults1"><?php echo $result ?></div>
```

Looking around online suggests I might need to use AJAX and jQuery but my tutor buddy insists this can be done within this one script. But I have no idea why my attempt does not work, can some one point me in the right direction???? :-)

Comment: Your tutor buddy is right, you don't need AJAX and jQuery - that is only if you want to load this data without reloading the page. Try doing a var dump of your results - it sounds like you aren't getting any data back from it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. We do not wish to reload the page. I did a var_dump and I get a 'null' value. So I am thinking I am not retriving those selected values correctly

Comment: That would be a valid assumption - usually I check my query at that point and make sure that it works in the database itself (via command line or phpmyadmin)

Comment: Just as a tip for debugging in the future - if you're not getting any content back, check the source of the page, where it cuts off shows where the code halted, if the page completes and the options appear but with no data, your accessing the data incorrectly, if the page completes and no option elements appear, you aren't reaching those lines in your code (i.e. empty results)